# Derivation of photon propagator from EM Lagrangian

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, quantum-electrodynamics, gauge-theory, propagator

I am following Ryder's Quantum Field Theory. In chapter 7, in order to derive the photon propagator, he first derives eq. 7.4 $$\mathcal{L}=\dfrac{1}{2}A^\mu[g_{\mu\nu}\partial^2-\partial_\mu\partial_\nu]A^\nu$$
from eq. 7.2 $$\mathcal{L}=-\dfrac{1}{4}F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}.$$
I am unable to figure out how he does that. So far all I have got is
$$\mathcal{L}=-\dfrac{1}{2}(\partial_\mu A_\nu\partial^\mu A^\nu-\partial_\mu A_\nu \partial^\nu A^\mu).$$
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: the Lagrangians are not equal. But since they only differ by a total derivative which vanishes for the action they are equivalent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Lagrangians are not identical, but they only differ by a total derivative. In other words, you get from the one to the other using partial integration.

For example, for the first term:
$$ -\frac 1 2 (\partial_\mu A_\nu) (\partial^\mu A^\nu) = -\frac 1 2 \partial_\mu \left( A_\nu \partial^\mu A^\nu \right) + \frac 1 2 A_\nu\, \partial_\mu \partial^\mu A^\nu \sim \frac 1 2 A_\nu\, \partial_\mu \partial^\mu A^\nu = \frac 1 2 A^\mu g_{\mu\nu} \partial^2 A^\nu \;. $$

Comment: What about $A_\mu~ \partial_\nu~ \partial^\mu ~ A^\nu $ I can't get it to $A^\mu \partial_\mu \partial_\nu A^\nu$

Comment: @S.S. where do you get $A_\mu \partial_\nu \partial^\mu A^\nu$ from?

Comment: $F_{\mu\nu}~ F^{\mu\nu} = (\partial_\nu A_\mu-\partial_\mu A_\nu)~ (\partial^\nu A^\mu-\partial^\mu A^\nu)$. So that we get a term like : $-\partial_\mu A_\nu~ \partial^\nu A^\mu $ . which then equals :$ A_\nu~ \partial_\mu  \partial^\nu A^\mu $. is some thing wrong :(

Comment: @S.S. Now I see, sorry, this question was quite a while ago ;)
You know in general $a_\mu b^\mu = a^\mu b_\mu$. A derivative in between doesn't make a difference, it commutes with the metric => $A_\mu \partial_\nu \partial^\mu A^\nu = A^\mu \partial_\nu \partial_\mu A^\nu$. Finally, $\partial_\nu \partial_\mu = \partial_\mu \partial_\nu$.
In the future, probably better create a new question in a case like this. I was probably the only one who (luckily) saw your comments ;)